# Validar Codigo si esta ejecutado correctamente

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola estuve tratando de organizar este codigo en el cual su funcion es que al subir una imagen y esta sea mayor al de 1mb me aparezca un mensaje que me el tamaño del archivo "El tamaño del archivo debe ser menor a 1 MB"

Me dijieron que validara el Id de "editarUser" y luego organizara el codigo, pero mi codigo sigue sin mostrar el el mensaje cuando inserto una imagen mayor a 1mb.

La parte de `$validator.addMethod` y muestra el parámetro de la imagen no se si me recoge correctamente el mensaje escrito.

```javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).off("click", "#btnEditar");
  $(document).on("click", "#btnEditar", function() {
    if ($("#editarUser").valid()) {
      var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
      // var fullQuality = canvas.toDataURL();
      // document.getElementById('firma').value = fullQuality;
      var imagen = new FormData($("#editarUser")[0]);
      var datosEnviar = $('#editarUser').serialize();

      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: imagen,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response) {
          if (response == 'Edicion exitosa de Usuario') {
            $.notify({
              message: response
            }, {
              type: 'success'
            });
            $('#editarUser')[0].reset();
            $(".cerrarModal").trigger("click");
            $('#misNotificaciones').css('display', 'none');
          } else {
            $('#misNotificaciones').css('display', 'block');
            // $.notify({
            //  message: response
            // }, {
            //  type: 'warning'
            // });
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
  $.validator.addMethod('filesize', function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param *
                                      1000000)
  }, 'File size must be less than {0} MB');
  $("#editarUser").validate({
    $rules: {
      firma: {
        filesize: 1
      }
    },
    message: {
      firma: {
        filesize: "El tamaño del archivo debe ser menor a 1 MB"
      }
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: ¿Y qué pasa cuando cambias `$rules` a `rules`?

Comment: Amigo te amo, si ero eso xD